# Action Bar with Login Page- already created tabs are shown

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have created the application using the ActionBar. I have used the **login page** in which I have getting the username and password from the user and then I have created the ActionBar tabs. In this application I have hided the action bar before loading the login page, after loading the login page then I have shown the action bar. Everything till now is working fine. After logoff the login page will be shown. In this time I have hided the action bar. **If I am login second time, the already created tabs is showing with newly created tabs.** That is If I am created 4 tabs means in the second time of the login 8 tabs will be shown.

Comment: Hi, Any update on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

then when you re-login you will have to check if there are already tabs existing that you don't want to have.

try to implement something like:

```
if (tabCount > 0) {
     //remove tabs
}

//build tabs
```

Comment: im pretty sure that you can also try some solution using the instanceState. though someone else has to explain that, im just learning it atm  :)